# more detailed information about the exception in xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

So I am trying to troubleshoot why adding an item to my dictionary causes an exception.

It turns out that I used a NSDictionary instead of NSMutableDictionary.

However the exception I saw... setobject format exception was no help at all.

Where do you look in xCode to get detailed exception information?  Or is this all that is given?

Comment: The exception gives you a selector name. Looking up that selector in the API documentation is usually a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunate that the emitted stacktrace contains the memory address of the method calls on the stack rather than their names.

I recommend using the debugger and setting a breakpoint at `objc_exception_throw`.  The debugger can tell exactly where the exception was made and what the arguments were.

markjnet provides [a nice writeup on exception debugging here](http://www.markj.net/debugging-tip-objc_exception_throw-breakpoint/).